Is it possible to get the velocity of raycasted points?
Ok, so to all the Python Blender wizards out there, I need help. I want to create a LiDAR simulator in Blender. I already have the basics working great (basic point cloud generation, noise, variable resolutions, ect.). However, one thing I really want to include is doppler. Just getting the velocity data per point would be great, but if it could be possible to color each point by its velocity (red moving away from emitter, blue moving toward emitter, white not moving relative to emitter, and everything in between being a gradient), that would be amazing. Currently, all the work is being done in Blender's geometry-nodes. Here is the full layout:

So, just to summarize: Is it possible to calculate the velocity of each point in the point cloud and color each point by that value? If so, how? I am using the latest version of Blender.
Blender file: 

Hello. velocity is the measure of a displacement in space relative to time. It is not an inherent parameter of a 3D object. You can store a 3D location into a custom attribute each frame, and on the next frame compare the distance between the current location and previous frame location, this will give you a measure of the velocity. Cheers

Where does the "velocity" of points in the point cloud come from ? As I read your GN graph, every thing is static, except the "noise" of the Ray Direction. Is it because the "LIDAR Em..." object is moving ?

Right, sorry. When I said "velocity of the points", I mean the velocity of the object they hit.

Is it the "Plane" object, connected as Target Geometry to the Raycast node ? Do you have a field with its velocity ? If so, you can start by plugging it to the Attribute socket. By the way, could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Yes, the "Plane" object is the current target of the LiDAR. Here  is the Blend file

(Using Blender 3.6.8)
Two modifications are required from the original settings:

Add a "velocity" field to the targetted object.
Compute the dot product between this sampled velocity with the ray from the LIDAR Emitter to get the sign of Doppler effect.

Setting the velocity field

1. A new GeometryNodes modifier is added to the targetted object.
2. The "velocity" field is attached to the targetted object using a Store Named Attribute node set in the Point domain.
3. For the demo, a basic field aligned with $Z$ axis is manufactured with positive (resp. negative) value for $Y \gt 0$ (resp. $Y \lt 0$).
Computing the Doppler effect

(NB: Only the modified part of the original GN graph is shown)
1. A Capture Attribute node set in Point domain is added to cache the Is Hit output of the Raycast node.
2. The Delete Geometry node Selection input is modified. Instead of deleting points at origin (as consequence of no hit from raycasting), the mask is based on the captured Is Hit boolean.
3. The Set Position node is modified. Its Selection mask is based on the captured Is Hit boolean. Points with no hit are not affected and remain at their original position, instead of moving to the origin.
4. The Raycast node is modified. A Named Attribute node is added to recover the "velocity" field attached to the Target Geometry. It is connected to the Attribute input socket. Its interpolated value at Hit Position is delivered through the Attribute output socket.
5. Let $L$ be the LIDAR Emitter Location, $H$ be the Hit Position and $\vec{V}$ be the interpolated velocity at $H$. The Doppler effect is characterized by the dot product between the unitary vectors aligned respectively to $\vec{LH}$ and $\vec{V}$. If this dot product is positive, the targetted position is moving toward the emitter. A value close to 1 means it is moving directly to the emitter. A negative value means the targetted position is moving away from the emitter. A value close to 0 means the targetted position is moving tangentially to the emitter. The green frame is enclosing the algebra to compute
$$ \frac{\vec{LH} \cdot \vec{V}}{\|\vec{LH}\| \ \|\vec{V}\|} $$
6. This Float value is cached using an other Capture Attribute node set in Point domain.
7. It is eventually saved using a Store Named Attribute under the name "doppler", to be used by the shader.

1. A new material named "Doppler" is added to the "LIDAR" object.
2. An Attribute node is used to recover the "doppler" value saved by the GN modifier. It is to notice that it is set in Instancer domain to get a value specific to each instanced object.
3. A Map Range node is used to bring the dot product from $[-1:1]$ to $[0:1]$.
4. A Linear colour ramp from red, to white, to blue is defined such that moving away targetted positions with negative dot product are rendered in red, while moving toward ones with positive dot product are rendered in blue.
Resources:

